# How to call a method in init method?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

My program looks like this:

```
-(id)init
{
    if ( (self = [super init]) )
    {
        //TargetWithActions *targetActions= [[TargetWithActions alloc] init];
        [self countDownSpeed123];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)countDownSpeed123
{
    countDownSpeed = 5.0f;
}
@end
```

warning: 'TargetWithActions' may not respond to '-countDownSpeed123'

I am getting the warning in this way. Where I am wrong in my program. Please explain ?
Thank You.

If I need to use the countDownSpeed value in another class, how can I retain the value ? How can I use in the other class? I think retain works for pointer types.

**EDIT:**

Sorry for my bad coding and negligence. I have did mistakes in my program which are very blunt.

Thanks for answering.

1. First: I did not declare the
   function (
   `-(void)countDownSpeed123;` )in
   interface.
2. Second: I did not include the
   following in my class where I needed
   the (countDownSpeed) value.

   ```
   TargetWithActions *targetActions= [[TargetWithActions alloc] init];
   [targetActions countDownSpeed123];
   ```

Now, I got what I need.

Thank You.

Comment: Did you remember to declare "countDownSpeed123" in your interface?

Comment: Need more than this. Please supply the interface, not just the implementation.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to declare it in interface. 
Thank You. Which is the better way to write the method. Using (id) or (void) ?

Comment: @Michael: Please put it as an answer :).

Comment: `init` should always have return type `id`.  `countDownSpeed123` should have return type of `void` if it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the class where you trying to use
   `TargetWithActions`, and in `TargetWithActions.m` make sure you
   have `#import
   "TargetWithActions.h"`.
2. In `TargetWithActions.h` make sure
   in your class declaration
   you declared the method `-(void)countDownSpeed123;`
3. Sorry I don't understand what are you trying to do with `countDownSpeed123`, it does not return anything (void) so I'm not quite sure what you want to `retain`. If the method returns simple value like `float` or `int` you don't have to retain it, it is passed by value - it will be copied.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad coding and negligence. I have did mistakes in my program which are very blunt. Thanks for answering.
First: I did not declare the function ( -(void)countDownSpeed123; )in interface.
Second: I did not include the following in my class where I needed the (countDownSpeed) value.
     TargetWithActions *targetActions= [[TargetWithActions alloc] init];
     [targetActions countDownSpeed123]; 
Now, I got what I need.
Thank You.